# Error to Create folder on SD card under DCIM folder in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sd-card

I know this is duplicate question but there is not available any solution for this. I have used latest API Level 24 and Test on API 23. I have to save image on SD Card with my App Name folder but folder is not created...

I have write following method but it not working

```
    public  void actionScreenShot(View view) {

        //enable drawing cache true
        imageContainer.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imageContainer.buildDrawingCache(true);

        //create image from layout
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageContainer.getDrawingCache());


        //String folder_path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/MyAppTest/"; //It's work properly
        //String folder_path = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/MyAppTest/"; //It's work properly 
        String folder_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAppTest"; //It's not work properly
        if (checkFile(folder_path)) {
            saveFile(new File(folder_path), bitmap);
        } else {
            File folder = new File(folder_path);
            if (folder.mkdirs()) {
                saveFile(folder, bitmap);
            } else {
                Log.d("Directory", " >> not created");
            }

        }
    }

    public void saveFile(File folder, Bitmap bitmap) {
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            File file = new File(folder, "temp.png");
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            success = checkDatabase(file.getPath());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (success) {
            Log.d("FILE", "success");
        } else {
            Log.d("FILE", "not success");
        }
    }

    public boolean checkFile(String myPath) {
        boolean isExist = false;
        try {
            File file = new File(myPath);
            isExist = file.exists();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return isExist;

    }
```

Permission is given also in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Log Trace as following...

```
10-05 17:08:09.424 2808-2808/packagename D/Directory  >> not created
```

If any solution available then help me...

Thanks....

Comment: `but it not working`. Please give better info. You should start telling if the folder is created.

Comment: You are not informing the user if mkdirs() fails. Put a toast there. You should   use more log and toast statements so you can tell us which and what happens and what you see.

Comment: post your stack trace. What about Run time permission?

Comment: Put a Toast in every catch block and display e.getMessage() in it.

Comment: log cat added...there is not created folder on sd card

Comment: String folder_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAppTest"; SEE ABOVE this line that both way working properly as mention in comment

Comment: Ok. Runtime permissions! Please react! This has been told you before.

Comment: where have you given permission in manifest file ? it should be on top of application tag

Comment: thanks @SrikarReddy

Answer (score 1):

here is the simple code to create folder in sdcard

```
// create a File object for the parent directory
File newFolder = new File("/sdcard/newFolder/");
// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
newFolder.mkdirs();
// create a File object for the output file
File outputFile = new File(newFolder, filename);
// now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String           
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: `newFolder.mkdirs();`. You should check the return value as mkdirs can fail. Display a toast for the user telling so. Then return. Do not continue with the code then.

Comment: You also should not blindly call mkdirs. Only if the directory does not exist.

Comment: @greenapps this is just a sample code to create folder it depends on requirements when and where do i want to make folder

Comment: No. You posted buggy code. I would fire you if i were your boss ;-).

Comment: @greenapps i have tested this code and then posted it .  i have used this code before in my project

Comment: Well OP told you that it failed. So what do i have to say more?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using API 23 and 24 (Marshmallow).
Google changed the permission strategy from API 23.
Reduce your target version to 22. It will work. If you want 23 or 24 then include code to request permission at run time.